# parse one segment out of all in flat file to JSON in mule

Tags: json, parsing, mule, dataweave, flat-file

I want to read a fixed width response from server.

Sample Response

```
PQRSBNGL1234567890AAHG
```

Here is sample ffd file

```
form: COPYBOOK
values:

- name: 'HOSPITALS'
  values:
  - name: 'BASIC-INFO'
    values:
    - { name: 'NAME', type: String, length: 4 }
    - { name: 'ADDRESS', type: String, length: 4 }
    - { name: 'PHONE-NUMBER', type: Integer, length: 10, format: { justify: ZEROES, sign: UNSIGNED } }
    - { name: 'ADMIN', type: String, length: 4 }
- name: 'WARDS'
  values:
  - name: 'BASIC-INFO'
    values:
    - { name: 'NAME', type: String, length: 4 }
    - { name: 'ADDRESS', type: String, length: 4 }
    - { name: 'NUMBER', type: Integer, length: 10, format: { justify: ZEROES, sign: UNSIGNED } }
    - { name: 'ADMIN', type: String, length: 4 }
```

I'm trying to read it through set payload
[set payload screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bgQr.png)

And then I'm trying it through dataweave script

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload map ( payload01 , indexOfPayload01 ) -> {
Wards: {
"Basic-Info": {
Name: payload01.WARDS."BASIC-INFO".NAME default "",
Address: payload01.WARDS."BASIC-INFO".ADDRESS default "",
Number: payload01.WARDS."BASIC-INFO".NUMBER default 0,
Admin: payload01.WARDS."BASIC-INFO".ADMIN default ""
}
}
}
```

But i'm getting below error

```
""java.lang.IllegalStateException - Structure WARDS not defined in schema
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Structure WARDS not defined in schema

    at org.mule.weave.v2.module.flatfile.FlatFileSettings.getStructure(FlatFileSettings.scala:131)

    at org.mule.weave.v2.module.flatfile.FlatFileReader.ffParser(FlatFileReader.scala:50)

    at org.mule.weave.v2.module.flatfile.FlatFileReader.doRead(FlatFileReader.scala:63)

    at org.mule.weave.v2.module.reader.Reader.read(Reader.scala:35)

    at org.mule.weave.v2.module.reader.Reader.read$(Reader.scala:33)

    at org.mule.weave.v2.module.flatfile.FlatFileReader.read(FlatFileReader.scala:22)

    at org.mule.weave.v2.el.MuleTypedValue.value(MuleTypedValue.scala:147)

    at org.mule.weave.v2.model.values.wrappers.DelegateValue.valueType(DelegateValue.scala:17)

    at org.mule.weave.v2.model.values.wrappers.DelegateValue.valueType$(DelegateValue.scala:16)

    at org.mule.weave.v2.el.MuleTypedValue.valueType(MuleTypedValue.scala:177)

    at org.mule.weave.v2.model.types.ArrayType.accepts(Type.scala:634)

    at org.mule.weave.v2.interpreted.node.executors.BinaryOverloadedStaticExecutor.findMatchingFunction(BinaryOverloadedStaticExecutor.scala:151)

    at org.mule.weave.v2.interpreted.node.executors.BinaryOverloadedStaticExecutor.executeBinary(BinaryOverloadedStaticExecutor.scala:78)

    at org.mule.weave.v2.interpreted.node.executors.BinaryStaticOverloadedFunctionExecutor.executeBinary(BinaryOverloadedStaticExecutor.scala:222)

    at org.mule.weave.v2.interpreted.node.BinaryFunctionCallNode.doExecute(FunctionCallNode.scala:81)

    at org.mule.weave.v2.interpreted.node.ValueNode.execute(ValueNode.scala:26)

    at org.mule.weave.v2.interpreted.node.ValueNode.execute$(ValueNode.scala:21)

    at org.mule.weave.v2.interpreted.node.BinaryFunctionCallNode.execute(FunctionCallNode.scala:78)

    at org.mule.weave.v2.interpreted.node.structure.DocumentNode.doExecute(DocumentNode.scala:26)

    at org.mule.weave.v2.interpreted.node.ValueNode.execute(ValueNode.scala:26)

    at org.mule.weave.v2.interpreted.node.ValueNode.execute$(ValueNode.scala:21)

    at org.mule.weave.v2.interpreted.node.structure.DocumentNode.execute(DocumentNode.scala:11)

    at org.mule.weave.v2.interpreted.InterpretedMappingExecutableWeave.$anonfun$writeWith$3(InterpreterMappingCompilerPhase.scala:264)

    at org.mule.weave.v2.module.writer.WriterHelper$.writeValue(Writer.scala:161)

    at org.mule.weave.v2.module.writer.WriterHelper$.writeAndGetResult(Writer.scala:139)

    at org.mule.weave.v2.interpreted.InterpretedMappingExecutableWeave.writeWith(InterpreterMappingCompilerPhase.scala:264)

    at org.mule.weave.v2.el.WeaveExpressionLanguageSession.evaluateWithTimeout(WeaveExpressionLanguageSession.scala:311)

    at org.mule.weave.v2.el.WeaveExpressionLanguageSession.$anonfun$evaluate$3(WeaveExpressionLanguageSession.scala:120)

    at org.mule.weave.v2.el.WeaveExpressionLanguageSession.doEvaluate(WeaveExpressionLanguageSession.scala:268)

    at org.mule.weave.v2.el.WeaveExpressionLanguageSession.evaluate(WeaveExpressionLanguageSession.scala:119)

    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.el.dataweave.DataWeaveExpressionLanguageAdaptor$1.evaluate(DataWeaveExpressionLanguageAdaptor.java:311)

    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.el.DefaultExpressionManagerSession.evaluate(DefaultExpressionManagerSession.java:105)

    at com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.SetPayloadTransformationTarget.process(SetPayloadTransformationTarget.java:32)

    at com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.TransformMessageProcessor.lambda$0(TransformMessageProcessor.java:92)

    at java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:159)

    at com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.TransformMessageProcessor.process(TransformMessageProcessor.java:92)

    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.func.CheckedFunction.apply(CheckedFunction.java:25)

    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.rx.Exceptions.lambda$checkedFunction$2(Exceptions.java:85)

    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.util.rx.Operators.lambda$nullSafeMap$0(Operators.java:47)

    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandleFuseable$HandleFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxHandleFuseable.java:165)

    at org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain$2.onNext(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:527)

    at org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain$2.onNext(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:522)

    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHide$SuppressFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxHide.java:127)

    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:204)

    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onNext(FluxOnAssembly.java:351)

    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSubscribeOnValue$ScheduledScalar.run(FluxSubscribeOnValue.java:178)

    at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:50)

    at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:27)

    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)

    at org.mule.service.scheduler.internal.AbstractRunnableFutureDecorator.doRun(AbstractRunnableFutureDecorator.java:151)

    at org.mule.service.scheduler.internal.RunnableFutureDecorator.run(RunnableFutureDecorator.java:54)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750), while reading `payload` as FlatFile.
Trace:
  at main (Unknown)" evaluating expression: "%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload map ( payload01 , indexOfPayload01 ) -> {
Wards: {
"Basic-Info": {
Name: payload01.WARDS."BASIC-INFO".NAME default "",
Address: payload01.WARDS."BASIC-INFO".ADDRESS default "",
Number: payload01.WARDS."BASIC-INFO".NUMBER default 0,
Admin: payload01.WARDS."BASIC-INFO".ADMIN default ""
}
}
}"."
```

Am i doing something wrong?
I just want to read the string and convert it into JSON object like the schema.

Am i doing something wrong?
I just want to read the string and convert it into JSON object like the schema.

Comment: Use XML text for Mule flows and configurations. DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. Code or sample data in images can't be copied and pasted in order to search about a problem or reproduce it. For more details read the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557).